# Reference a lists and input data from value field

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

**DoDIC List:**

[image]

**MPSRON List**

[image]

I need column "b" on the MSPRON sheet to reflect the value of column a.  but column As value and the associated values of column b in the DODIC list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean column A and B in Dodic are formula not just value and you want only B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Vlookup:

`=Iferror(VLOOKUP(A2,DODIC!$A$52:$B$89,2,FALSE),"")`

$A$52:$B$89 is the Data in DODIC sheet change it to correspond to the First and last Row in your Data
$ to keep the array reference fix so you can drag the formula down
2 to return Column B of DODIC
False to return the exact value
IFERROR in case no match to return empty ""
Drag it down without changing it will return the corresponding value
When finish you can copy the result and paste special values so it will not change if you move it

Comment: If you are satisfied kindly accept the answer